# SP Designer 2013 15.0.4551.1001

Tags: sharepoint-designer, designer-workflow

I am running Microsoft SP Designer v15.0.4551.1001 and I cannot open a workflow in the designer for a 365 SharePoint Online site.
I get the following error -

```
Windows workflow foundation, part of .Net Framework 3.0, must be installed to use this feature
```

I have tried to clear the cache files at - 
**%APPDATA%\Microsoft\Web Server Extensions\Cache
%APPDATA%\Microsoft\SharePoint Designer\ProxyAssemblyCache
%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WebsiteCache**

Still no joy.  Any tips advise how to resolve?

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: Also tried installing - 
https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/confirmation.aspx?id=42009

Rebooted client and still experiencing the same issue.

Comment: try to check the provided answers here https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/azure/en-US/372ec877-ede0-4df3-9dda-fb056d9689fa/sharepoint-2013-designer-error-windows-workflow-foundation-part-of-net-framework-30-must-be?forum=sharepointadmin

Answer (score 0):

Does the workflow has some lookups which are referenced. this could also cause the above mentioned problems

Check out this blog [here](https://praveensharepointknowledgebase.wordpress.com/2017/01/11/sharepoint-reusable-workflowhas-lookup-migration/) for more information about workflows with lookups.

you can also try this method.

To resolve this issue please update your designer with the hotfixes in sequence. Make sure the designer is NOT open.

http://support2.microsoft.com/hotfix/KBHotfix.aspx?kbnum=2837667&kbln=en-us

http://support2.microsoft.com/hotfix/KBHotfix.aspx?kbnum=2727100&kbln=en-US

Once installation is complete open the site once again. A restart may not be necessary. If you still get the same issue then clear your designer cache by running this

rmdir "%LOCALAPPDATA%\Microsoft\WebsiteCache\" /s /q
rmdir "%APPDATA%\Microsoft\SharePoint Designer\ProxyAssemblyCache\" /s /q

Then Restart you PC. Found in [this](http://agouda.blogspot.de/2015/02/sharepoint-designer-failed-to-load-this.html) blog. Also make sure you read comments section, as people do post some solutions that might work for someone. you could also try those methods if something does not work for you.

Comment: Hi Manish,
I have tried the above and still no joy.
Does it matter if I am running Windows 10 Enterprise?

Comment: I dont think so that should have any impact on the above as long as you are sharepoint designer licensed version.

Comment: I will try building a VM and try if the installation works on a clean install.
Nightmare.